# how to regex across line breaks

Tags: regex, line-breaks

I am trying to capture the 3 numbers below across three lines

```
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
Matches 
1 - 60
out of 92
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

I just cannot get my regex string to work. I have the following so far :-

```
Matches.*?\n.*[0-9]*.*?-.*?[0-9]*\nout of.*?[0-9]*
```

i have tried it on a few online regex testors and in c#.

*NEW INFO*

I discovered the actual problem was because the input text contains a CR (no LF) to indicate new line so obviously the match for \n does not work. so now to match the new line i am using [\r|\r\n].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+` and add parenthesis around them to capture it.

```
Matches.*?\n.*([0-9]+).*?-.*?([0-9]+)\nout of.*?([0-9]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/11)

- `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times.
- `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.

**OR**

If you use the `*` after `[0-9]` then you need to change the previous pattern `.*` to `.*?` because `*` is greedy by default. You need to make it as non-greedy by adding `?` after `*`. So that it won't eats up the following zero or more digits.

```
Matches.*?\n.*?([0-9]*).*?-.*?([0-9]*)\nout of.*?([0-9]*)\n
```

If you use this `Matches.*?\n.*?([0-9]*).*?-.*?([0-9]*)\nout of.*?([0-9]*)` regex, it won't capture the last digits because of `[0-9]*`(zero or more digits), so you need to match also the following character to capture that last number.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vJ8uR6/12)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
(?m)Matches[\s\S]*?\nout of[ ]*[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?Matches|(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+).*?out\s*of\s*(\d+)
```

You can try this.Dont forget to put flag `s` and `g`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/76